# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My `createGroup` class does not work properly every time I click on a drawer menu bar device is refreshing the app. Here is my fetching group method:

```
private void FetchGroup() {
        String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mStore.collection("/users" + userId + "/groups").get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
            groupModelArrayList.clear();
            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                GroupModel groupModel = new GroupModel(documentSnapshot.getString("grupAdi"), documentSnapshot.getString("grupAciklamasi"),
                        documentSnapshot.getString("grupResmi"), (List<String>)documentSnapshot.get("grupNumaralar"), documentSnapshot.getId());
                groupModelArrayList.add(groupModel);
            }
```

ERRORS:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but userswEfW4DUgl0gFPv7J8afrTisIiXD3/groups has 2
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.(CollectionReference.java:45)
> at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(FirebaseFirestore.java:366)
> at com.example.smsapplication.createGroup.CreateGroupFragment.FetchGroup(CreateGroupFragment.java:140)
> at com.example.smsapplication.createGroup.CreateGroupFragment.onCreateView(CreateGroupFragment.java:108)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1899)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1823)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1760)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:547)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)`

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but userswEfW4DUgl0gFPv7J8afrTisIiXD3/groups has 2

Because of the following line of code:

```
mStore.collection("/users" + userId + "/groups").get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

Why? Because when you concatenate:

```
"/users" + userId + "/groups"
```

You'll get as result:

```
userswEfW4DUgl0gFPv7J8afrTisIiXD3/groups
```

And not:

```
users/wEfW4DUgl0gFPv7J8afrTisIiXD3/groups
//
```

As it should. To solve this, please add `/` inside your reference like this:

```
mStore.collection("/users/" + userId + "/groups").get().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
//
```

See the `/`? Now you'll have 3 segments and not only 2.

Comment: Hey Aurelius. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?